# Allow child network to use parent network for internet access - but don't show parent network clients

Tags: networking, routes, ip

I have two Linksys WiFi routers. The first one (**orange network**) with the IP address 192.168.0.1 is connected to the internet. The second one (**green network**) with the IP address 10.10.10.10 is connected to the **orange network**.

Its physically not possible to get the 10.10.10.10 router directly connected to the internet (in-between the internet and the **green network** are 3 floors/levels and it's not possible to get a second network cable between them)

I set up the network structure inside Cisco Packet Tracer and with this configuration (see image) I can see and ping the clients inside the **orange network**.

But I don't know how to set this up, that the 10.10.10.10 router only can access the 192.168.0.1 address for only internet access (the clients inside the green network are not allowed to see the clients inside the orange network).

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is (tested and working):

Install on the ROUTER inside the **green network** the newest DD-WRT version.

After installing DD-WRT go into the Web-Admin-GUI of the **green network** router, to add **ONE** command line.

Inside the Web-Admin-GUI goto:
"Administration" --> "Commands" and add this line:

`iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP` *(192.168.0.0/24 is the network number of the **orange network**)*

**IMPORTANT:** that the router don't forget this line at reboot - save it with the button "Save Firewall".